# Client side join using withTracker not waiting for reply from server

Tags: reactjs, meteor, coffeescript

I store the members of a list within each List document as an array of members. I can then grab an array of all member Ids associated with a List.

I am hoping to then query mongo for that set of user records. I do this by passing the array of Ids to a `Members.find $all` call.

My issue is that the `this.props.listMember`s returns nothing as the IF statement is skipped. How can I be sure my listMembers waits for activeList to be back?

Thanks for any guidance!

```
    export default MemberListContainer = withTracker( (props) =>
      handle = Meteor.subscribe('allMembers')
      loading = !handle.ready()
      activeList = Lists.findOne({ _id: Session.get("activeList") })

      if activeList
        listMembers = Members.find({_id: {$in: [activeList.members] }}).fetch()

      {
        loading
        activeList
        listMembers
        currentUser: Meteor.user()
      }
```

Publications on Server:

```
Meteor.publish('allLists', () ->
  Lists.find({ }) )

Meteor.publish('allMembers', () ->
  Members.find({ }) )

Meteor.publish('users', () ->
  Meteor.users.find({ }) )
```

Comment: Could you please add the publication code?

Comment: Yep! Added to above.